# A predicate within a predicate?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm new here. I wish to ask a question regarding predicate logic:

I was given three predicates:

**parent(p,q): p is the parent of q.**

**female(p): p is a female.**

**p = q: p and q are the same person.**

Now, I was tasked with translating this sentence: Alice has a daughter.

My answer was: **There exists a q such that parent(Alice,female(q)).**

The answer given is: **There exists a q such that female(q) AND parent(Alice,q).**

Is it correct to have a predicate (in this case, female) within another predicate (in this case, parent)?

Much appreciated.

Comment: No; a *prdicate* letter is used to write a "statement": $Red(x)$ used with the *term* $book$ gives $Red(book)$. Terms are *variables*, *constants* ore "complex" terms built-up with *function* letters. Thus, the syntax of a bynari predicate like $Parent(x,y)$ needs two "names" (i.e. *terms*) to be "completed".

Comment: Compare with *arithmetic* : $<$ is a (binary) *predicate* (or relation), while $+$ is a (bynary) *function*. The "result" of $2 < 4$ is *true*, while the "result" of $2+4$ is $6$, a number. Thus, the expression $2+4$ is a "name" for the number $6$, while $2 < 4$ is an arithmetical sentence.

Comment: Perhaps your confusion stems from the fact that you read $\mathrm{female}(q)$ word by word, as the English phrase "the female $q$". But, a predicate is *not* an adjective; you should read $\mathrm{female}(q)$ as the sentence "$q$ is female". Then it is clear that "Alice is the parent of '$q$ is female'" doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intuitively, a predicate in a predicate doesn't make sense; predicates only take terms as arguments. Using the normal convention of abbreviating predicates and terms by letters ($P(p,q)$ for parent, $F(q)$ for female, $a$ for Alice), your example is
$$\exists q\ P(a,F(q))$$
which is interpreted as "Alice is the parent of *true*" – absurd, since children aren't truth values. In other words, your attempt does not produce a well-formed formula.

The given answer translates as
$$\exists q\ F(q)\land P(a,q)$$
which is well-formed.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not in this particular case. You conclude that by substitution.

female(q) can have two values : true or false.

- For female q, female(q)=true you have : parent(Alice,true).
- For non-female q, female(q)=false you have : parent(Alice,false).

Since false and true are not humans (they are truth values) the proposition **parent(Alice,female(q))** is false for all values of **q**.

So there does not exist a **q** such that **parent(Alice,female(q))**.

Your predicate within a predicate is a well-formed formula. True and false can be used as terms of a predicate. But the formula does not express the required concept.

Comment: What does this add to the existing two-year-old answer?

Comment: @Noah An explanation in the same terms used by the OP. Furthermore, I've edited it to clarify that OP's formula is well-formed.